# Print Number of Message per Second

Tags: c#, timer, mqtt

I have an infinite while loop. I want to have a print of number of messages at every second. It should print after every second the count of the messages. for example if I have 500 messages in 1 second then it should print  the count as 500 after the messages and then in if it is 500 in next 1 sec then it should print 500 again after the messages Here is my code:

```
static void SimulatePublish()
{
  var counter = 1;
  while (true)
  {
    counter++;
    var testMessage = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
      .WithTopic("MqttData")
      .WithPayload($"Payload: This is my Code")
      .WithAtMostOnceQoS()
      .WithRetainFlag()
      .Build();
    if (_client.IsConnected)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"publishing at {DateTime.UtcNow}");
      _client.PublishAsync(testMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, It should print after every second the cound of the messages. for example if I have 500 messages in 1 second then it should show the count as 500 and then in if it is 500 in next 1 sec then it should print 500 again after the messages

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69342966/edit) the original question rather than add details in comments. Also you need to show what you have tried and how it didn't work. You can not just state a requirement and expect SO to write the code for you, it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int messagesDiff = 0;
long startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds(), timeDiff;

TimerCallback printingLambda = (o) =>
{
    timeDiff = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds() - startTime;
    Console.WriteLine("Messages per second: " + messagesDiff / (double)timeDiff);
    startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    messagesDiff = 0;
};

Timer timer = new Timer(printingLambda, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

while (true)
{
    //public message
    messagesDiff++;
}
```